# Overlapping Dates in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want a query to identify the `Vehicle Registration Numbers` having more than 1 policy with different `Insurance Company ID`, with overlapping dates. [Check this image for the datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXhxN.jpg)

```
 SELECT Vehicle_N0.*
   FROM excel as Vehicle_N0
  WHERE Vehicle_N0 IN (SELECT Vehicle_N0  
                         FROM excel 
                        GROUP BY Vehicle_N0    
                       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Insurance_id) > 1) 
  ORDER BY vehicle_n0
```

using this query i got the `Vehicle Registration Numbers` having more than 1 policy with different `Insurance Company ID` but **how to get the overlapping dates.**

I tried this query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM excel 
 WHERE begin_date <= end_date 
    OR begin_date >= end_date;
```

But i didn't get the overlapped dates.

Comment: please post expected result,actual result as text and not images

Comment: The expected result is i want to get the overlapped dates from my table. I tried to do that but i am failed

Comment: Look at this link to know more on how to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Have you checked this question? Maybe it will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490553/detect-overlapping-date-ranges-from-the-same-table

Comment: yeah i checked it out but its not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `exists()` to see if a `Vehicle_N0` has an overlapping entry with a different `Insurance_Id`:

```
select v.*
from excel as v
where exists ( -- only return rows where this query would return row(s)
  select 1
  from excel as i 
  where i.Vehicle_N0 = v.Vehicle_N0      -- Vehicle_N0 is the same
    and i.Insurance_Id <> v.Insurance_Id -- Insurance_Id is not the same
    and i.end_date > v.begin_date        -- date range overlaps
    and v.end_date > i.begin_date        -- date range overlaps
  )
order by v.Vehicle_N0
```

Comment: I am getting the correct result but, i don't understand how it works....

Comment: @JeroldJoel I have updated my answer with some comments, let me know if that helps. Is there a particular part you do not understand?