# SQL consolidate overlapping dates based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I'm trying to merge overlapping dates between Admit and discharge dates of patients. There are a few edge cases which I couldn't cover in the query.

**Input**

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| ID | Admit_Dt   | Discharge_Dt |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | 12/30/2020 | 07/14/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | 01/02/2021 | 07/14/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | 06/16/2021 | 07/14/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 2  | 03/04/2021 | 03/25/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 2  | 05/01/2021 | 05/10/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 3  | 06/01/2021 | 06/05/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| ID | Admit_dt   | Discharge_dt |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  | 12/30/2020 | 07/14/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 2  | 03/04/2021 | 03/25/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 2  | 05/01/2021 | 05/10/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 3  | 06/01/2021 | 06/05/2021   |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

**Query** I used the logic that was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490553/detect-overlapping-date-ranges-from-the-same-table) But this doesn't cover the edge case for ID 2 and 3. Also the subquery is slower when the data is huge. Is it possible to tackle this problem using LAG?

```
SELECT dr1.* FROM Member_Discharges dr1
INNER JOIN Member_Discharges dr2
ON dr2.ADMIT_DT> dr1.ADMIT_DT 
  and dr2.ADMIT_DT< dr1.DISCHARGE_DT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  I would suggest using a cumulative max to determine when an "island" starts and then aggregate:

```
select id, min(admit_dt), max(discharge_dt)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_Discharge_dt >= Admit_Dt then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by admit_dt, discharge_dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(Discharge_dt) over (partition by id
                                           order by Admit_Dt, Discharge_dt
                                           rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_Discharge_dt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bed0903ad9f9ca1f853c8426f5a831af) is a db<>fiddle.

The innermost subquery is retrieving the maximum discharge date *before* each row.  This allows you to check for an overlap.  The middle subquery counts up the number of times there is *no* overlap -- the beginning of a group.  And the outer query aggregates.

Comment: This is amazing! Do you mind explaining the logic in the initial subquery?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another "gaps-and-islands" solution**

- Use `LAG` to determine if the previous `Discharge_Dt` is earlier than the current `Admit_Dt`, if so we have a starting point
- Number the islands using `COUNT OVER`
- Group by the `ID` and the new grouping number, and take the min and max dates

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN LAG(Discharge_Dt, 1, '19000101')
                  OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Admit_Dt)
                < Admit_Dt THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                    ORDER BY Admit_Dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM StartPoints
)
SELECT ID, Admit_Dt = MIN(Admit_Dt), Discharge_Dt = MAX(Discharge_Dt)
FROM Groupings
GROUP BY ID, GroupId
ORDER BY ID, GroupId;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e8d34678143658204439902f2076c60)