# Calculate weekly hours of operation in T-SQL from overlapping date/time data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to calculate the number of hours of operation per week for each facility in a region. The part I am struggling with is that there are multiple programs each day that overlap which contribute to the total hours.

Here is a sample of the table I am working with:

| location | program | date | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 09-22-21 | 14:45:00 | 15:45:00 |
| a | 2 | 09-22-21 | 15:30:00 | 16:30:00 |
| b | 88 | 09-22-21 | 10:45:00 | 12:45:00 |
| b | 89 | 09-22-21 | 10:45:00 | 14:45:00 |

I am hoping to get:

| location | hours of operation |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1.75 |
| b | 4 |

I've tried using SUM DATEDIFF with some WHERE statements but couldn't get them to work. What I have found is how to identify the overlapping ranges([Detect overlapping date ranges from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490553/detect-overlapping-date-ranges-from-the-same-table)), but not how to sum the difference to get the desired outcome of total non-overlapping hours of operation.

Comment: And please show your desired output.

Comment: Actually show us the query you tried.

Comment: Is it safe to assume times are always rounded to the nearest 15 minutes?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that.

Comment: How did you get 2.15 hours for location a?

Comment: that was a typo - my bad.

Comment: Still don't understand your calculation. The difference between 14:45 (when program 1 starts) and 16:30 (when program 2 ends) is only 1.75 hours total. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, very poor multitasking happening right now. thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe you are trying to identify the total hours of operation for each location. Now because some programs can overlap, you want to rule those out. To do this, I generate a tally table of each possible 15 minute increment in the date and then count the time periods that have a program operating

### Identify Total Hours of Operation per Date

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OperationSchedule
CREATE TABLE #OperationSchedule (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Location CHAR(1),Program INT,OpDate DATE,OpStart TIME(0),OpEnd TIME(0))
INSERT INTO #OperationSchedule
VALUES ('a',1,'09-22-21','14:45:00','15:45:00')
,('a',2,'09-22-21','15:30:00','16:30:00')
,('b',88,'09-22-21','10:45:00','12:45:00')
,('b',89,'09-22-21','10:45:00','14:45:00');

/*1 row per 15 minute increment in a day*/
;WITH cte_TimeIncrement AS (
    SELECT StartTime = CAST('00:00' AS TIME(0))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(minute,15,StartTime)
    FROM cte_TimeIncrement
    WHERE StartTime < '23:45'
),
/*1 row per date in data*/
cte_DistinctDate AS (
    SELECT OpDate
    FROM #OperationSchedule
    GROUP BY OpDate
),
/*Cross join to generate 1 row for each time increment*/
cte_DatetimeIncrement AS (
SELECT *
FROM cte_DistinctDate
CROSS JOIN cte_TimeIncrement
)

/*Join and count each time interval that has a match to identify times when location is operating*/
SELECT Location
    ,A.OpDate
    ,HoursOfOperation = CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT StartTime) * 15/60.0 AS Decimal(4,2))
FROM cte_DatetimeIncrement AS A
INNER JOIN #OperationSchedule AS B
    ON A.OpDate = B.OpDate
    AND A.StartTime >= B.OpStart
    AND A.StartTime < B.OpEnd
GROUP BY Location,A.OpDate
```

Comment: I see why you were asking about the 15 min increments. Thank you so much, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method without having to round to nearest 15 minute increments:

```
Declare @OperationSchedule table (
        ID       int Identity(1, 1)
      , Location char(1)
      , Program  int
      , OpDate   date
      , OpStart  time(0)
      , OpEnd    time(0)
        );

 Insert Into @OperationSchedule (Location, Program, OpDate, OpStart, OpEnd)
 Values ('a',  1, '09-22-21', '14:45:00', '15:45:00')
      , ('a',  2, '09-22-21', '15:30:00', '16:30:00')
      , ('b', 88, '09-22-21', '10:45:00', '12:45:00')
      , ('b', 89, '09-22-21', '10:45:00', '14:45:00')
      , ('c', 23, '09-22-21', '12:45:00', '13:45:00')
      , ('c', 24, '09-22-21', '14:45:00', '15:15:00')
      , ('3', 48, '09-22-21', '09:05:00', '13:55:00')
      , ('3', 49, '09-22-21', '14:25:00', '15:38:00')
      ;

   With overlappedData
     As (
 Select *
      , overlap_op = lead(os.OpStart, 1, os.OpEnd) Over(Partition By os.Location Order By os.ID)
   From @OperationSchedule os
        )
 Select od.Location
      , start_date = min(od.OpStart)
      , end_date = max(iif(od.OpEnd < od.overlap_op, od.OpEnd, od.overlap_op))
      , hours_of_operation = sum(datediff(minute, od.OpStart, iif(od.OpEnd < od.overlap_op, od.OpEnd, od.overlap_op)) / 60.0)
   From overlappedData                  od
  Group By
        od.Location;
```