In T-SQL identifying date range overlaps by customer
I'm trying to figure out if there is one way to code the overlap rather then building out 4 distinct queries in T-SQL.
We have a single table called T_DATA, it has columns customer_id, cust_identifier, start_dt, end_dt, and others.
Here is a sample of what our data looks like and we need to return customers 1 and 2.

We are looking to find all the rows that fall into these scenarios.

short of building out nested queries and 4 different joins is there some other simplified ways to build out any kind of overlap.

Look up gaps and islands.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117962/what-is-a-simple-and-efficient-way-to-find-rows-with-time-interval-overlaps-in-s

For sql-server this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490553/detect-overlapping-date-ranges-from-the-same-table

... Where not (Start DT > End DT or End DT < Start DT) unless I'm missing something.

Please do not use images, use table markdown.

A common point for ALL of those scenarios is the Start_Dt for the next record will come before the End_Dt of the current record.
You can check for this in a single pass through data (without needing a self-join, or any joins) using the LEAD() window function. This should give the data you need:
WITH Next_Start As (
    select td.*
       , lead(Start_dt) over (partition by customer_id order by customer_identifier) next_start_dt
    from T_DATA td
)
SELECT *
FROM Next_Start
WHERE next_start_dt < End_Dt

If you'd rather key in on the second record in an overlapping pair, instead of the first, you could do it with LAG(), like this:
WITH Next_Start As (
    select td.*
       , LAG(End_dt) over (partition by customer_id order by customer_identifier) prior_end_dt
    from T_DATA td
)
SELECT *
FROM Next_Start
WHERE Start_Dt < prior_end_dt

This does have the potential to show records that are out-of-sequence for the customer_identifier rather than just overlapping within a given customer. If this is a possibility, you may want to order by Start_Dt instead of customer_identifier within the window definitions.

For your example you can use this query to find over lapping ranges:
select distinct dr1.* 
from  T_DATA dr1
inner join  T_DATA dr2
on dr2.Start_dt > dr1.Start_dt -- start after dr1 is started
  and dr2.Start_Dt < dr1.End_Dt -- start before dr1 is finished




Customer_ID
Customer_Identifier
Start_Dt
End_Dt




1
11
2024-01-01
2026-01-01


2
13
2023-01-01
2024-02-02


2
14
2022-01-01
2025-01-01



use this to detect which overlap scenario applies:
select distinct dr1.*,dr2.*,
     CASE 
       WHEN dr2.Start_dt > dr1.Start_dt AND dr2.End_Dt > dr1.End_Dt THEN 'Scenario 1'
       WHEN dr2.Start_dt < dr1.Start_dt AND dr2.End_Dt < dr1.End_Dt THEN 'Scenario 2'
       WHEN dr2.Start_dt > dr1.Start_dt AND dr2.End_Dt < dr1.End_Dt THEN 'Scenario 3'
       WHEN dr2.Start_dt < dr1.Start_dt AND dr2.End_Dt > dr1.End_Dt THEN 'Scenario 4'
       ELSE 'Other Scenario'
    END as Scenario   
from  T_DATA dr1
inner join  T_DATA dr2
on (dr2.Start_dt > dr1.Start_dt -- start after dr1 is started
  and dr2.Start_Dt < dr1.End_Dt) -- start before dr1 is finished
OR
 (dr1.Start_dt > dr2.Start_dt -- start after dr2 is started
  and dr1.Start_Dt < dr2.End_Dt) -- start before dr2 is finished

